# GET Headers send from HTTP to PHP

Tags: php, get, http-headers

I have a software that opens the contact-form.php page, and when it opens i get the following HTTP Headers:

http://192.168.1.7:8091/syg/new/contact-form.php?lead_id=1601734&phone_number=6977060744&first_name=John

How can i present these values to my form on PHP? The form has a typical format of:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="your_phone" placeholder="phone" required>
```

Comment: What header? Do you mean url? I am not exactly sure what you are asking. Do you want your form to point to that url or you want the values in your form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can check `$_GET` values like this:-

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="your_phone" placeholder="phone"  value = "<?php echo (!empty($_GET['phone_number'])) ? $_GET['phone_number'] : '' ;?>" required>
```

Comment: Thank you very much this helped a lot!